# SPServices does not work in the document library

Tags: sharepoint-server, spservices

Tell me why SPServices does not work in the document library, there are no problems in the list, but the library does not work out either, the Russian language name, tried both GUID and by name...it's still useless...

```
script type="text/javascript" src="/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js"
```

```
$().SPServices.SPUpdateMultipleListItems({
    listName: "Office",
    CAMLQuery: "",
    batchCmd: "Update",
    valuepairs: [["ValueItem", 'Update']],
    debug: false,
    completefunc: null
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPUpdateMultipleListItems does not work in the 'project documents library' where a collection of documents is organized.